# JSON and Web API - how do I receive a simple JSON object into a Web API using built in types (without JQuery)?

Tags: json, api, web

I'm working on a system that sends a simple JSON object to a C# .NET Web API in the form:

{property1: "string1", property2: "string2"}

I want to receive this JSON into the web api. I can't initially use a custom object when I receive the JSON into the web API (because the system I'm working writes stuff into the DB automagically, and for this to work, only the built-in C# types can be used at the point that data reaches the web api).

The system doesn't utilise JQuery, so that's not an option. How can I accept this JSON into the Web API?

Comment: Stringify your input, add it to the body of http post.  Add a WebApi controller with a single string parameter(don't forget the [FromBody] attribute).  use JSON.NET to deserialize the json string, this can be strongly typed OR DYNAMIC.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of [dynamic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/dynamic) type:

```
[Route("your route")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]dynamic properties)
{
    var property1 = properties["property1"];

    var property2 = properties["property2"];

    //your code
}
```

or

```
[Route("your route")]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]object properties)
{
    var property1 = (properties as dynamic)["property1"];

    var property2 = (properties as dynamic)["property2"];

    //your code
}
```